# Is there a formal name for the "where were you..." argument?

Tags: terminology

When a major event, such as a protest, happens, one of the common arguments from critics is something along the lines of "where were you six months ago?" The underlying, unspoken accusation being "you should have been organizing sooner."

This strikes me as a sort of fallacious argument, but is there an actual name for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a version of the [Nirvana Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_fallacy).

The popular translation of Voltaire is:

> The perfect is the enemy of the good.

In the case you describe: even if voting for a preferred candidate in the past would have been better than than protesting the actions of the non-preferred candidate now, that does not mean that protesting now is a bad idea.

The ideal state (taking action in the past) is better than the achievable state (taking action now), but the choice between those two is a false dilemma. One can not choose to alter the past.